# kryo serializing of class (task object) in apache spark returns null while de-serialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, apache-spark, kryo

I am using java spark API to write some test application . I am using a class which doesn't extends serializable interface . So to make the application work I am using kryo serializer to serialize the class . But the problem  which I observed while debugging was that **during the de-serialization the returned class object becomes null and in turn throws a null pointer exception** . It seems to be closure problem where things are going wrong but not sure.Since I am new to this kind of serialization I don't know where to start digging.

**Here is the code I am testing :**

```
package org.apache.spark.examples;


import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;




/**
 * Spark application to test the Serialization issue in spark
 */
public class Test {

    static PrintWriter outputFileWriter;
    static FileWriter file;
    static JavaSparkContext ssc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String inputFile = "/home/incubator-spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/InputFile.txt";

        String master = "local";
        String jobName = "TestSerialization";
        String sparkHome = "/home/test/Spark_Installation/spark-0.7.0";
        String sparkJar = "/home/test/TestSerializationIssesInSpark/TestSparkSerIssueApp/target/TestSparkSerIssueApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.closure.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.apache.spark.examples.MyRegistrator");
        // create the Spark context
        if(master.equals("local")){
            ssc = new JavaSparkContext("local", jobName,conf);
            //ssc = new JavaSparkContext("local", jobName);
        } else {
            ssc = new JavaSparkContext(master, jobName, sparkHome, sparkJar);
        }
        JavaRDD<String> testData = ssc.textFile(inputFile).cache();
        final NotSerializableJavaClass notSerializableTestObject= new NotSerializableJavaClass("Hi ");
        @SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unchecked"})
        JavaRDD<String> classificationResults = testData.map(
                new Function<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(String inputRecord) throws Exception {                   
                        if(!inputRecord.isEmpty()) {
                            //String[] pointDimensions = inputRecord.split(",");
                            String result = "";

                            try {
                                FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/home/test/TestSerializationIssesInSpark/results/test_result_" + (int) (Math.random() * 100));
                                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(file); 
                                InetAddress ip;
                                ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                                outputFile.println("IP of the server: " + ip);

                                result = notSerializableTestObject.testMethod(inputRecord);
                                outputFile.println("Result: " + result);

                                outputFile.flush();
                                outputFile.close();
                                file.close();

                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } 

                            return result;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("End of elements in the stream.");
                            String result = "End of elements in the input data";
                            return result;
                        }
                    }

                }).cache(); 

        long processedRecords = classificationResults.count();

        ssc.stop();
        System.out.println("sssssssssss"+processedRecords);
    }
}
```

**Here is the  KryoRegistrator  class**

```
package org.apache.spark.examples;

import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;

public class MyRegistrator implements KryoRegistrator {
    public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
        kryo.register(NotSerializableJavaClass.class);
    }
}
```

**Here is the class I am serializing :**

```
package org.apache.spark.examples;

public class NotSerializableJavaClass {
    public String testVariable;

    public NotSerializableJavaClass(String testVariable) {
        super();
        this.testVariable = testVariable;
    }

    public String testMethod(String vartoAppend){
        return this.testVariable + vartoAppend;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things I notice; your NotSerializableJavaClass doesn't have a no-arg constructor. Kryo doesn't like that. Also, I'm far from an expert but the serialisation looks unusual. I would have expected to see a `Kryo kryo = new Kryo();  kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, objectToSerialise);` or similar kicking about in there

Comment: Although [it appears that serialising a no-arg constructor object is possible, just not easy](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/issues/detail?id=5)

Comment: Hi Richard, The spark API has inbuilt kryo API's implemented which does the same as you pointed out by doing `Kryo kryo = new Kryo();  kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, objectToSerialise);` . But what do you suggest how do I go forward ? Will the no arg constructor help me overcome this issue ?

Comment: if you can easily put in the no-arg constructor I certainly would. I can't promise it will sort your problem as I haven't used kryo within spark but I know that 90% of the time when I have a problem its either "no no-arg constructor" or "nested class"

Comment: Though the whole point of me trying this was that we have a situation where I might get 3rd party jars which can have any structure and they may not be serializable and changing the structure of class would defeat the whole point but none the less that's a head start . Thanks

Comment: Harsh, were you able to resolve your error with the suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `spark.closure.serializer` only supports the Java serializer. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html about `spark.closure.serializer`

Comment: True but registering your java class with Kryo causes the java serializer to be used. I did this with Guava's BiMap. Without registering BiMap the task failed to serialize.

Comment: So another issue I'm running into that causes a task from a closure to be unable to serialize. I'm using an external scala library in a closure. How do I determine which class is causing the problem. For all I know it could be in a transitive dependency.

Comment: Using external scala library in a closure is fine if you make sure you don't use them out of the closure. For debug, you can use Java option `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`.

Comment: I'm reading in a text file using rdd.textFile(source).map{closure} inside the closure I use json4s (which uses java jackson) and get a task not serialized failure. The closure returns an rdd of case classes so I don't need to use it outside. Why the task not serialized, and why can't I use the json4s outside the closure? Do I need to register something with Kryo?

Comment: E.g., you create some object in json4s outside the closure, and use it in the closure. Then when serializing the closure, it also need to serialize the object from json4s. If the object is not serializable, you will get the serializable failure.

Comment: But you are saying that using json4s outside the closure is fine and I knew that--no spark code involved, no closure serialization. How do I use it inside the closure? I thought you said "Using external scala library in a closure is fine"? Using it inside causes task not serializable errors since the closures are distributed via Spark.